# Hide child controls in UserControl with another control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am writing a custom control deriving from *UserControl*. In it are some controls that I want to prevent from being accessible (some textboxes, comboboxes). They are to become available for interacting only when the user clicks an 'Edit' button.

I read about *KeyPreview* but it is only available for forms. I find redirecting all the events to a common handler that checks if editing mode is enabled too much of a hassle.

Is there any way to put another transparent control over the others (Z orderwise), that will intercept all mouse and keypress events but renders the controls normally? Or maybe there is a different solution?

Edit:
I want to receive mouse events on the control that covers the others. I need those for Drag and drop and moving the custom control.

Comment: Normally i would use a FormView in the UserControl that changes it's mode from `ReadOnly` to `Edit` when the user clicks on edit. All other approaches are more a hassle than this.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Would that work with winforms?

Comment: The normal way to do this would be to put the controls into a `Panel` -- setting `panel.Enabled = false` would disable user interaction with the controls.  The controls will appear dimmed, which is not what you asked for, but is probably what most users would expect.

Comment: Use the Enabled or Visible property.  Anything else just drives the user nuts after banging away at the control for a minute without getting any result.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgR3cD4jh2M

Comment: @möter: sorry, i was sure that i've seen an ASP.NET tag ;)

Comment: @Justin: As I wrote, I'd like for the controls to render normally. Also, setting Panel.Enabled = false disables events for the panel as well. I need events on the panel though.

Comment: I agree, you should use a container for your controls (a panel for instance) and change the value of the Enabled property depending on the edit state. Users would expect this behavior.

Comment: @ken2k: But then I wouldn't be able to receive any mouse or keypress events on that container.

Comment: @möter: yes, but what do you expect the user to be able to do? For example, what would you like the user to do with a combobox that is not available for interacting? I don't see how Keypress could be relevant for a control that is not available for user interactions.

Comment: @ken2k: Sorry I should have written in the question. Please see my edit.

Comment: If you really need your sub-controls to raise events, then you can attach a common event to all of them. I mean, you can loop through MyControl.Controls then attach your event to all of your sub-controls (textbox, combobox...etc.). You'll then have an unique handler to manage your drag/drop event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your's Enabled property in your UserControl and use it.

```
private new bool Enabled
        {
            get { return _enabled; }
            set
            {
                foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control c in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (c is SomeTypeThatShouldBeExcluded)
                        continue;
                    c.Enabled = value;
                }
                _enabled = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This comes pretty close to what I need. Thanks.